# Rave Report, Preview Window in Delphi

Tags: delphi, preview, rave-reports

Is it possible to change the description of interface elements in the default Preview Window triggered by RvSystem1.Execute?

[image]

I need them (File, Page, Zoom etc.) in my native language (not in Enlgish).

Regards
Artik

Answer (score 0):

well, i had to do this a long time a go, from what i remember, i only have to change the files Preview.dfm, status.dfm, setup.dfm located on C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi\Rave\Lib to the language that i wanted